# Getting Location Update only when app is in Background

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cllocationmanager

I am trying to get the location updates Particularly when the application is in background. When the application enters background it should send the location updates for every n minutes
First I tried with the Foreground, it is working fine. I copied the same code to the applicationDidEnterBackground, I am unable to print the Location Updates. I don't know where I am struck please help me.

in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

  locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  locationManager.delegate = self;
  locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

and

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
  int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
  double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
  int minutes = decimal * 60;
  double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
  NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                   degrees, minutes, seconds];
  latLabel.text = lat;
  degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
  decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
  minutes = decimal * 60;
  seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
  NSString *longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                     degrees, minutes, seconds];
  longLabel.text = longt;
}
```

I tried pasting these methods in the AppDelegate. It is not working :( . Help me

Comment: Did you create entry for UIBackgroundModes for location in plist ?

Comment: Thank you for reply. Its my mistake, I forgot to add that one. Now it is added, and I can see in the log now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply paste the code there and expect your application to run in the background.  You have to register it as an app that runs in the background.  See the section **Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks** in [this article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3)

Comment: I knew it silly to ask this question. To make it sure I am asking this. After adding the UIBackgroundModes in the app. It is printing the location every minute. If I want to print the update every 10 mins, then I have no other option to go for Long-Running Background Tasks. Am i Right ?

Comment: You must use long running tasks if you expect it to run for more than 10 minutes.  Updates will come asynchronously, you don't get to control that.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. Am really confused here "you don't get to control that" . Because When i am receiving that update after 10 mins, I wish i will other function to save the co-ordinates as the log.

Comment: The docs state that location changes will come as events.  Did you read the section titled "Tracking the User’s Location"?

Comment: Ya. I have went through the document especially "Background location services" . So we will receive those updates as events , such as remote notification ?

Comment: I didn't read the particulars but I can only assume that you implement delegate methods that get called.

Comment: Its quite annoying that i am asking too many questions. Sorry.Can you help me with some sample piece of code which will print/update location every 10 mins. I will be really thankful

Comment: Sorry, I've never done it personally ^^ I'm just going by the docs.

Answer (score 2):

As per discussion with comments I suggested you to create entry in  plist.

`UIBackgroundModes for location in plist`

And this helped.

**EDIT**

When you log the coordinate you need to save time somewhere probably in NSUserDefaults. After that when next time you come to log you need to find difference between current time and stored in NSUserDefaults. If interval is what you want than do log the coordinate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it is .Now the lat and longt is printing every minute. I am trying to print it for every 10 min. Do you have any idea?

Comment: No i am not going to save the time details. Instead I am going to post the values to another server. The code which I have posted above - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation                    is called every minute. Do you have any idea that how to schedule it ?

Comment: NSTimers comes in mind but NSTimers doesn't work in background modes. So you can not use NSTimers for scheduling.

Comment: Using scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1200 it is called every 20 mins. But when this  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation is called, it is keep on calling by itself. Whether I am doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Be careful here as I told you NSTimers doesn't work in background. When you go in background all timers will stop working. and for your question it will be called automatically when new location is available. You can not force CLLocationManager to update on certain period of time.

Comment: Yeah I have read in many sites too saying that the Timers will not work in background. But I am surprised that its working here. I will paste the code which I am using,please please let me know where I am wrong

Comment: counterTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                   beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                       // If you're worried about exceeding 10 minutes, handle it here
                   }];
    count=0;
    theTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:600
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(Location)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];